# In Ruby on Rails how I can add Image in Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have following code in my model. This is in my app/models/product.rb.

I am reworking ready to go shop.

Line `http://ia.media-avant.com/images/B/#{image_url}` points to DB and then to image on site. I have `image_url` column in my DB.

For testing purpose I would like to point this image for a while to my `public/images/image.jpg` folder.

How the syntax for it should look ?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image
    "http://ia.media-avant.com/images/B/#{image_url}"
  end

  def title
    "http://www.media-avant.com/title/#{title_id}/"
  end

  def cart_action(current_user_id)
    if $redis.sismember "cart#{current_user_id}", id
      "Remove from"
    else
      "Add to"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define an instance method that overrides the column accessor:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image
    "http://ia.media-avant.com/images/B/#{image_url}"
  end

  def image_url
    "public/images/image.jpg"
  end
end
```

Once you're done testing, you should of course remove the method.

Comment: OR you could define Product::image_url in your tests which is basicly the same, but it does not affect other environments

Comment: @IvanSelivanov if the question is about running unit tests, you are absolutely right. My answer was about testing "in the browser". The use case is not clear in the question, however.

Comment: Thanks Lads ;) !! Those are great ideas ;)

Comment: out of curiosity, did you mean "testing in the browser" or "running unit/functional/integration tests"? My answer is only valid for the former.